# Trying to pass value of form selections and have onclick display in textfield

Tags: java, forms, variables, onclick

None of the variables are properly set, right now I'm just trying to get the value of my radio selection to display in a field using the quote button aQuote()...then I also want to be able to take the input from width and height to create a final total outputting to that field, but I can't even achieve the first thing.

```
var form = 1;
var chosen = document.inputForm.pack.value;
var width = 1;
var length = 1;

function aquote() {

  document.getElementById("qprice").value = chosen ;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="inputForm" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="submit.php">  
    <fieldset>
<label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
        <br />
        <label>Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" />
        <br />
        <label>Mobile:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" />
        <br />
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<div class="textRightform">
<label class="radio2">Pool package:</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pack" value="2000"
            checked="checked" />Rectanguluar
            <input type="radio" name="pack" value="2500" onClick="getCheckedRadio()"/>Rectangluar with Spa
            <input type="radio" name="pack" value="3000" />Round Pool
            <input type="radio" name="pack" value="3500" />Round Pool with Spa<br><br>
         <label>Length meters</label><input name="length" type="number" size="7" maxlength="4"><br>
         <label>Width meters</label><input name="width" type="number" size="8" maxlength="4"><br><br>
         <input name="quoteshow" type="text" value="" id="qprice" readonly /><br>
          <input type="button" name="quote" id="qpress" value="Show Quote" onClick="aquote()"/>
   </div> <br> <br>
        <div class="buttonLeft">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />  <!--Hidden token field-->
        <input type="text" id="hp" name="hp" />                                         <!--Hidden honeypot field-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send form" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
 </head>

 <body>
  <form id="inputForm" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm();" action="submit.php">  
    <fieldset>
<label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
        <br />
        <label>Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" />
        <br />
        <label>Mobile:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" />
        <br />
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
<div class="textRightform">
<label class="radio2">Pool package:</label><br>
 <input type="radio" name="pack" value="2000"
            checked="checked" />Rectanguluar
            <input type="radio" name="pack" value="2500" onClick="getCheckedRadio()"/>Rectangluar with Spa
            <input type="radio" name="pack" value="3000" />Round Pool
            <input type="radio" name="pack" value="3500" />Round Pool with Spa<br><br>
         <label>Length meters</label><input name="length" type="number" size="7" maxlength="4"><br>
         <label>Width meters</label><input name="width" type="number" size="8" maxlength="4"><br><br>
         <input name="quoteshow" type="text" value="" id="qprice" readonly /><br>
          <input type="button" name="quote" id="qpress" value="Show Quote" onClick="aquote()"/>
   </div> <br> <br>
        <div class="buttonLeft">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />  <!--Hidden token field-->
        <input type="text" id="hp" name="hp" />                                         <!--Hidden honeypot field-->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send form" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
 </body>
 <script>

 function aquote()
 {
 var radios = document.getElementsByName('pack');
var packValue =0;
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
       packValue = radios[i].value;
    }
}
alert(parseInt(packValue));
}
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: did you checked any radio button

Comment: var chosen = $('input:radio[name=pack]:checked').val();
I imagine it's not so simple adding jquery in to pure javascript code?

Comment: you need to import jQuery libraries for that

Comment: no you need to add jQuery libraries,I posted javascript solution also can u see that

Comment: Still giving me bad values, not sure why. I think I need to re-write the function from scratch but I don't know how to parse the value still.

Comment: Yes! Thankyou! Works great with final doc.getid.